# how can i stack step line graph series above each other C#

Tags: c#, charts

i want to create a graph in C# for multiple variables against time
for instance i have two variables,

1) Grid_electricity available, with two possible values 0,1

2) Battery level, with 4 possible values, 0,1,2,3 (dead, low, medium, high)

and similarly more, 
[image]

no i want to plot them above each other, as (image attached) , any possible suggestions? 
[image]

Comment: Well if you are drawing this onto a surface, offset the Y values by 0 or the previous series max ...

Comment: what does your data structure look like that's holding this data? provide some code and we can help modify it

Comment: `public enum enumGridAvailabilty { NO_GRID = 0, GRID_AVAILBLE } ;
public enum enumBTY_LEVEL { BTY_Dead = 0, BTY_Low, BTY_Half, BTY_High, BTY_Full } ;` Though i have made different charts for now! any suggestions are welcomed

Comment: @madihamalik Did you get any workaround till now?